# Convert database string to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

I have a field in one of my database tables, a sample of this field looks like so ; `["1","4","7"]`. Those are keys to a reference in another table. What i want to do is fetch the field and ideally loop through the values and get the data from the referenced table. As you will notice, `["1","4","7"]` is PHP declaration for an array but for the life of me, I am unable to parse it as an array. How do i parse it as an array? What am I missing?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Instead of solving this you should probably look into storing these relations in a separate table / normalizing your database. That will save you a lot of headaches later on.

Comment: because what PHP sees is not an array but rather a string

Comment: Jay Blanchard.. I did try.. But I managed to figure out.. Im so useless.. turns out i forgot that i json_encoded my data.. lol.. sorry guys..

Comment: It is not an array, it is a string. Also, please try to post your code as well so that viewers know what you have tried and can give you better answers. Thanks.

Comment: Don't what to be "that guy" but you need to normalize your database. Create a pivot table with `table1_id | table2_id` instead of having an "array" of foreign keys

Comment: Haha, I have very valid reasons for this approach but thanks for the advice.. Much appreciated.

Comment: It's hot in here, but I'm going to keep my clothes on. Anyway, thanks for the invitation.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to decode and convert it into an array with PHP's `json_decode` function.

**Example:**

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode('["1","4","7"]'));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: echo array returns an error. Edit or a warning. But it does not return the array.

Comment: Was supposed to be a print_r. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem is that your database column store a string PHP array representation.

So you should use the function [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php)

By the way it's a strange way to store relation in a database